# How do I print a group of text matching a regex in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'd like to print only few groups from text matching a regex. How can I do that in the Linux command line?

What other tools for text processing are there in Linux?

Comment: if you just want to print some portions of text that match a regex, use `grep -o`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two programs I use frequently for this purpose are [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) and [`awk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gawk).

[`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) has additional flavours, such as [`egrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/egrep) and [`fgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fgrep) which alter how the given pattern is used.

The [`Unix Toolbox`](http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.xhtml#awk) has a few examples on `sed`, `awk` and links to more resources!

Answer (score 2):

Perl!

```
perl -nE '/foo (\w+) bar/ and say "group 1 is $1";'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you might do it is through lang consoles, such as Ruby or Node.js. Both have access to filesystem and a host of things you can do with it. As I come from the front-end web world, I personally find Node.js's syntax to be easy to use.